# What are the licensing requirements for Sitecore Universal Tracker?

Tags: xdb, xconnect, universal-tracker

What are the licensing requirements around Sitecore Universal Tracker? 
- Would, say, a license for xDB suffice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar to xConnect there is no licensing requirement for the universal tracker. Sitecore only has license requirements for the CM, CD, PRC, and REP servers. In production and pre-production.

As always consult your sales rep for any licensing requirements specific to your organisation.